# C TCP Client won't connect to the server

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client, server

I'm writing a basic TCP Client that I'm trying to connect to a TCP Server that I have already made sure works. For some reason, my client won't connect to the server. It will not get past the connection attempt. Both client and server are on the same machine, I'm using 127.0.0.1 for both and port 8080. Any pointers as to why? Thanks!

```
/*
Usage: tcpclient <server_ip> <server_port> <client ip> <input_file> <output_file> <size of send/receive buffer>
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char* server_ip;
    char* client_ip;
    char* input_file; 
    char* output_file;
    int server_port, buffer_size;

    server_ip = argv[1];
    server_port = atoi(argv[2]);
    client_ip = argv[3];
    input_file = argv[4];
    output_file = argv[5];
    buffer_size = atoi(argv[6]);

    int sockfd = 0;
    int bitsSent = 0;
    int bitsReceived = 0;

    char sendBuffer[buffer_size];
    char recvBuffer[buffer_size];

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    memset(recvBuffer, '0', sizeof(recvBuffer));
    memset(sendBuffer, '0', sizeof(sendBuffer));
    memset((char *)&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr)); 


    /* Check command line arguments */
    if (argc != 7) {    
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Create the socket */
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);

    /* Attempt to connect to server */
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0) {
        printf("Err: Couldn't connect");
        return 1;
    }   

    /* Open the input file to read */
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(input_file, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening the file");
        return(-1);
    }

    /* Receive the data then write to sendBuffer */
    while ((bitsSent = read(sockfd, recvBuffer, buffer_size)) >0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", bitsReceived);
        fwrite(recvBuffer, 1, bitsReceived, fp);
    }

    if (bitsReceived < 0) {
        printf("Read Error");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Define"won't connect". Error message? Core dump? Computer explodes?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. It enters the if statement where I attempt to make the connection to the server: if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)

Comment: So what does connect actually return? YOu should get used to the debugger

Comment: So? *What's the error?* Get rid of the `printf()` and use `perror().` No hope of a solution until we know what the problem is. When you get an error,  print the error. You already know it failed: just printing that information is useless. Same applies after the read/write loop.

Comment: `bitsSend`/`bitsReceived` such namings are defintily missleading.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `connect` before you create a socket. Since `sockfd` is zero at that point, you're trying to `connect` standard input.

Comment: `socket()` *is* being called, and checked for error, before `connect()` is called, so how is it connecting before creating a socket?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Check the edit history. The question was edited into a totally different question.

Answer (score -2):

I don't remember if that was relevant but instead of:

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
```

try:

```
inet_aton("127.0.0.1",&server_addr.sin_addr);
```

And as the other reply says you forgot to create the socket:

```
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0){
    perror("Error al crear el socket");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Why? Do you think there's something wrong his code?

Comment: I remember having problems with that line of code and using this other line fixed it. I don't remember why but I'll take a look at my project later because I'm sure I explained it in the comments

Comment: Thank you both! I have updated the code to include creating the socket - I completely missed that. Same problem, however - still unable to connect unfortunately

Comment: @deuseux12 If that fixed your problem, you need to understand why, and what it was that you had done wrong on that occasion. Recommending this fix as a solution to everything without understanding why it fixed what it did fix in your case is just programming by cargo-cult.

Comment: yeah thx I have it explained in my project, but I don't remember why it was. I'll take a look when I can.